# Test meta tags with playwright

Tags: automated-tests, meta-tags, playwright

I want to test meta tags of the web application in Playwright, but I haven't found any info in the official documentation. Can somebody advise me with meta data testing?

For example, I have tried to test:
`<meta name="description" content="something">`

```js
test("Meta data", async ({ page }) => {
         await page.goto(env.baseUrl)
         const metaDescription = page.locator('meta [name="description"]')
         await expect(metaDescription).toHaveText("something")
})
```

and the result is:

- The received string is ""
- waiting for selector 'meta [name="description"]'

What is wrong and how to test it in the right way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your locator selector is matching nothing. `meta [name="description"]` targets elements inside a `meta` element with the attribute `name="description"`. To target the meta element itself you have to use `meta[name="description"]` (note the removed space).

Additionally, the meta element holds the text in the `content` attribute. That's why `toHaveText` can't work. Try `toHaveAttribute` instead.

Here's the fixed version:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
    
test('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://your-site.com');
  const metaDescription = page.locator('meta[name="description"]');
  await expect(metaDescription).toHaveAttribute('content', 'something')
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, now it works fine for all meta tags! :)

Comment: Cool. could you mark the question as solved then. :)

Comment: I'm using a library which updates the `<meta property="og:description" content="this">` after a short timeout. I've tried your solution but it's flaky. Sometimes it randomly fails because the library takes too long. Is there a way to actively wait for attribute to yield an expected value?

Comment: `await expect(elem).toHaveAttribute` does exactly this — wait for `elem` to have this value or time out and throw an error. Might be that your library is slower than the default timeout, so it's worth increasing `timeout`.